# Creating non-linear function to calculate points per distance in reversed order.

Tags: functions, polynomials

I have a small game in which I want to give points according to closeness to location, so the maximum points will be given for the minimal number = 1.
It's similar to [GeoGuesser](http://geoguessr.com/) game.
Here is the data :
The max `distance` is 30,000,000 (minimum points) = 0 points
The min `distance is 1 (maximum points) ~ 1000 points
The function should not be linear (as I understand) since I want the distribution to be smaller on the low distance and higher on the higher distances.
I.E. 1m should give 1000 pts. , 1000m should give 900 pts. , 10000m should give 700 pts. etc... (so each meter has less affect as we come near the maximum).

I've found a similar function but the ranges are different and I wan't able to adjust it to my data : [example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4500%2aexp%28-x%5E2%2F%282%2a200000%29%29+%2B+2000%2aexp%28-x%5E2%2F%282%2a20000000%29%29+from+x%3D0+to+x%3D20000+and+y%3D0+to+y%3D7000)
Thank you